# Toggling the value when click using React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a toggle button that changes the theme when click but I am not able to the theme to change when I click the toggle button. But when I use the react dev tool to change from true to false value manually and the theme changed accordingly. I am trying my hands on Context API and I don't know what I am missing. Thanks a lot and in advance.

```
//App.js

import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Booklist from './components/Booklist'
import ThemeContextProvider from './contexts/ThemeContext'
import ThemeToggle from './contexts/ThemeToggle';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeContextProvider>
        <Navbar/>
        <Booklist/>
        <ThemeToggle/>
      </ThemeContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//ThemeContext.js
import React,{useState, createContext} from 'react'
export const ThemeContext = createContext(null)

function ThemeContextProvider(props) {
 const [datastate, setDataState ] = useState({ 
    isLightTheme: true,
    light: { fontcolor: '#555', ui: '#ddd', bg: 'DarkSlateBlue' },
    dark: { fontcolor: 'white', ui: 'gray', bg: 'DarkSlateBlue'}
})
    
const changeTheme = () =>{
   setDataState({isLightTheme:!datastate.isLightTheme})
}
console.log(datastate.isLightTheme)
return (
        <div>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{...datastate, changeTheme:changeTheme}}>
                {props.children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}

ThemeContextProvider.context = ThemeContext

export default ThemeContextProvider

//ThemeToggle.js
import React,{ useContext } from 'react'
import {ThemeContext} from '../contexts/ThemeContext'

const ThemeToggle = () => {
    const contextType = useContext(ThemeContext)
    const {changeTheme} = contextType
      return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={changeTheme}>Change Theme</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ThemeToggle


//Booklist.js
import React,{ useContext } from 'react'
import {ThemeContext} from '../contexts/ThemeContext'

function Booklist() {
    const contextType = useContext(ThemeContext)
    const{isLightTheme, light, dark} = contextType
    const theme = isLightTheme ? light : dark
    return (
        <div className='book-list' style={{color:theme.fontcolor,background:theme.bg}}>
            <ul>
            <li style={{background:theme.ui}}>Harry Porter</li>
            <li style={{background:theme.ui}}>The Alchemist</li>
            <li style={{background:theme.ui}}>The Book Thief</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Booklist

//Navbar.js
import React,{ useContext } from 'react'
import {ThemeContext} from '../contexts/ThemeContext'

function Navbar() {
    const contextType = useContext(ThemeContext)
    const{isLightTheme, light, dark} = contextType
    const theme = isLightTheme ? light : dark
    console.log(theme)
    return (
        <nav style={{background:theme.ui, color:theme.fontcolor}}>
          <h1>Context App</h1>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some trials and errors, all I need to do is to change from

```
  const changeTheme = () =>{
   setDataState({sLightTheme:!datastate.isLightTheme})
  }
```

to

```
   const changeTheme = () =>{
   setDataState({...datastate,isLightTheme:!datastate.isLightTheme})      
}
```

and it works.